# wordpress breadcrumbs the last element isn't in the tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make a breadcrumbs, but I don't understand why the last element(url - where we are) isn't in a tag, how can I fix it. I need that the last elem will be I a tag - . I would appreciate if you help me.

php:

```
function breadcrumbs($separator = ' <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-1g" aria-hidden="true"></i> ', $home = 'Main_page') {

    $path = array_filter(explode('/', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)));
    $base_url = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
    $breadcrumbs = array("<a href=\"$base_url\">$home</a>");

    $last = end( array_keys($path) );

    foreach( $path as $x => $crumb ){
        $title = ucwords(str_replace(array('.php', '_'), Array('', ' '), $crumb));
        if( $x != $last ){
            $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="'.$base_url.$crumb.'">'.$title.'</a>';
        }
        else {
            $breadcrumbs[] = $title;
        }
    }

    return implode( $separator, $breadcrumbs );
}
```

Comment: Just read your code, you have a condition in it... `if( $x != $last )`

Comment: To @vard 's point: **`else { $breadcrumbs[] = $title; }`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the last item check to ad the link. Here is the modified code:

```
function breadcrumbs($separator = ' <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-1g" aria-hidden="true"></i> ', $home = 'Main_page') {

    $path        = array_filter(explode('/', parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)));
    $base_url    = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
    $breadcrumbs = array("<a href=\"$base_url\">$home</a>");

    foreach( $path as $x => $crumb ){
        $title = ucwords(str_replace(array('.php', '_'), Array('', ' '), $crumb));

        $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="'.$base_url.$crumb.'">'.$title.'</a>';
    }

    return implode( $separator, $breadcrumbs );
}
```

Comment: Now it's in the tag, but now separator after the last element how can I make it between tag a?